# UITextview font styling issue

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am setting font to `UITextView` . It works. I am also making the text entered in the `UITextView` as bold by selecting the text in `UITextView`. My problem is if I give
font size I cannot make the text bold.

Comment: Are you trying to set font for whole text in TextView or only for selected text?

Comment: for the whole textview

Comment: Can you share some code that you have done? I tried this and it worked txtViewTest.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(34)

Comment: have you tried NSAttributedString?

Comment: NSString * subString = @"<String that you want to make bold>";
[attStr addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} range:[string rangeOfString:subString]];
[<Your UILabel Object> setAttributedTitle:attStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: try this one if it is useful for you then tell me so i can give the answer it

Comment: try setting `typingAttributes` property.

Answer (score 0):

try it .

```
self.txtView.text=@“Life is an opportunity , Don’t west your time !”;

NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.txtView.text];
NSString *word= @"Life is an opportunity"; 
NSRange range=[self..txtView.text rangeOfString:word];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:range];
[self.txtView setAttributedText:string];
[self.txtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:15]];
self.txtView.alpha=1;
```